# Writing a unit test for asynchronous code in Dart Test

Tags: dart, dart-async, dart-unittest

After reading the [Unit Testing with Dart](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-unit-tests/#asynchronous-tests) somehow I'm still can not understand how to use it with `Future`s.

For example:

```dart
void main() {
  group('database group', () {
    setUp(() {
      // Setup
    });

    tearDown(() {
      // TearDown
    });

    test('open connection to local database', () {
      DatabaseBase database = null;

      expect(database = new MongoDatabase("127.0.0.8", "simplechat-db"),
          isNotNull);

      database.AddMessage(null).then((e) {
        expectAsync1(e) {
          // All ok
        }
      }, onError: (err) {
        expectAsync1(bb) {
          fail('error !');
        }
      });
    });

    // Add more tests here
  });
}
```

So in the test I create an instance of base abstract class `DatabaseBase` with some parameters to actual [MongoDb](https://github.com/vadimtsushko/mongo_dart) class and immediately check if it created. Then I just run some very simple function: `AddMessage`. This function defined as:

```dart
Future AddMessage(String message);
```

and return `completer.future`.

If passed `message` is null then the function will fail completer as:  `.completeError('Message can not be null');`

In actual test I want to test if `Future` completed successfully or with error. So above this is my try to understand how to test `Future` returns - the problems is this this test **does not fail**  :(

Could you write in answer a little code example how to test functions that return `Future` ? And in test I mean - sometimes I want to test return (on success) value and fail test if success value is incorrect and another test should fail then function will fail `Future` and enter to `onError:` block.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing function containing async function in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092719/testing-function-containing-async-function-in-dart)

Answer (score 5):

I just re-read your question, and I realize I was answering sort of the wrong question...

I believe you're using `expectAsync` incorrectly. `expectAsync` is used to wrap a callback with N parameters and ensure that it ran `count` times (default 1).

`expectAsync` will ensure that any exceptions are caught by the test itself and are returned. It does not actually run any expectations by itself (bad nomenclature.)

What you want is just:

```dart
database.AddMessage(null).then(
  (value) { /* Don't do anything! No expectations = success! */ },
  onError: (err) { 
    // It's enough to just fail!
    fail('error !');
  }
);
```

or if you need to ensure that the test completed to some particular value:

```dart
database.AddMessage(null).then(
  expectAsync1((value) { /* Check the value in here if you want. */ }),
  onError: (err) { 
    // It's enough to just fail!
    fail('error !');
  }
);
```

---

Another way of doing this is to use the `completes` matcher.

```dart
// This will register an asynchronous expectation that will pass if the
// Future completes to a value.
expect(database.AddMessage(null), completes);
```

or to test for an exception:

```dart
// Likewise, but this will only pass if the Future completes to an exception.
expect(database.AddMessage(null), throws);
```

If you want to check the completed value, you could do as follows:

```dart
expect(database.AddMessage(null).then((value) {
  expect(value, isNotNull);
}), completes);
```

See:

- http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/matcher.html#completes
- http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/unittest.html#expectAsync0
- http://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-unit-tests/#asynchronous-tests

Comment: On my comp the `fail` is crashing the test with exception and stacktrace, etc... Is there any other way to explicity `fail` the test ?

Comment: If you want to check the completed value:
`expect(database.AddMessage(null), completion(isNotNull));`

Answer (score 3):

A `Future` can be returned from a `test()` method - this will cause Unit Test to wait for the `Future` to complete.

I usually put my `expect()` calls in a `then()` callback. For example:

```
test('foo', () {
  return asyncBar().then(() => expect(value, isTrue));
});
```