# Why to mark unit test as async in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I am newbie in Flutter as well as TDD and I do not understand why and when to mark unit test as async in flutter.

Looking through the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/unit/mocking) I found this code snippet:

```dart
// Create a MockClient using the Mock class provided by the Mockito package.
// Create new instances of this class in each test.
class MockClient extends Mock implements http.Client {}

main() {
  group('fetchPost', () {
    test('returns a Post if the http call completes successfully', () async {
      final client = MockClient();

      // Use Mockito to return a successful response when it calls the
      // provided http.Client.
      when(client.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => http.Response('{"title": "Test"}', 200));

      expect(await fetchPost(client), const TypeMatcher<Post>());
    });

    test('throws an exception if the http call completes with an error', () {
      final client = MockClient();

      // Use Mockito to return an unsuccessful response when it calls the
      // provided http.Client.
      when(client.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => http.Response('Not Found', 404));

      expect(fetchPost(client), throwsException);
    });
  });
}
```

If you look carefully you will noticed that first test is marked as **async** and the second is not. Why is that? What is different between these two test(except the cases) so that the first one has to be **async**?

Thanks :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing function containing async function in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092719/testing-function-containing-async-function-in-dart)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to use `await`, you have to mark a callback or function in general as `async`.

---

In your case:

```dart
expect(await fetchPost(client), const TypeMatcher<Post>());
```

The `await` is needed because the result of the function execution matters. They are expecting exactly a `Post` type to be returned, hence, they need the `await`.

In the other case:

```dart
expect(fetchPost(client), throwsException);
```

It only matters that an exception is thrown, but the result is irrelevant.

### When to mark callback with `async` when testing

Whenever you need `await`, you mark your callbacks with `async`. In general, I would advise always awaiting functions in tests because the tests will otherwise run in parallel, which could show undesired behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was confused a lot. I have one more question, will the first test pass if we omit async/await since we are using mock object? Thanks again :)

Comment: @hogar I do not know what `fetchPost` looks like, but assuming that it does not return a `FutureOr` type, **no** `->` I just took a look at the linked article and the test will not pass. You can try it if you want.