# How does testing for synchronous changes in an async function work in Dart's test package?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, mockito, future

I'm following [Reso Coder](https://resocoder.com/)'s [video](https://resocoder.com/2022/02/08/flutter-testing-guide-for-beginners-part-1-unit-tests-setup/) about unit tests in Flutter / Dart. In the video, he is testing a class that makes an async call to a remote service (mocked using Mockito):

**Class being tested (not the full code)**:

```
Class ServiceChangeNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
 final Service _service;

 ServiceChangeNotifier(Service this._service);

 bool _isLoading = false;
 bool get isLoading => _isLoading;

 List<int> _res = [];
 List<int> get res => _res;

 Future<void> doService() async {
   _isLoading = true;
   notifyListeners();
   _res = await _service.runService();
   _isLoading = false;
   notifyListeners();
 }
```

Notice he's changing `_isLoading` to true before the service call, and then to false after.

Now, in the test, he wants to verify that the loading state gets updated correctly to true before the service call, and then to false after the service. To do so, he is setting the call to the async service method into a Future variable, then asserts the true change, then awaits on the future variable, and then asserts for false:

**Unit test code**

```
 final ServiceChangeNotifier sut = ServiceChangeNotifier(serviceMockup);
 
 test('....',
  () async {
    // test setup...

    final future = sut.doService() // 1
    expect(sut.isLoading, true); // 2
    await future; // 3
    expect(sut.isLoading, false); // 4

    // ...
  }
```

I understand why you can await the method *before* testing for true, because it will change to false before the expect(true) gets to run. What I don't understand is how the check for true (line 2 above) works. Is the logic of line 1 (future assignment) the one that triggers the execution of the doService method, or is it the await in line 3?

I suspect I'm missing something basic about how Future/await works and/or how expect() works in the test library. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092719/testing-function-containing-async-function-in-dart) is somewhat related to this question, but here I'm *not* asking about the async part of the doSerivce method, but rather how the synchronous assignments to _isLoading is being evaluated in light of the asynchronous call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute an asynchronous function, as much of it as possible is executed synchronously; that is, its function body is executed until it reaches an `await` (which is syntactic sugar for returning a `Future` and registering appropriate completion callbacks).

So given:

> ```dart
> final future = sut.doService() // 1
> expect(sut.isLoading, true); // 2
> await future; // 3
> expect(sut.isLoading, false); // 3
> ```

1. `sut.doService()` is invoked immediately.  `doService`'s body immediately sets `_isLoading = true`, invokes `notfifyListeners()` [sic], invokes `_service.runService()`, and then returns a `Future`.
2. `sut.isLoading` at this point is `true`.
3. The `Future` returned by step 1 is `await`ed, so execution returns to the event loop.  The `Future` from `_service.runService()` eventually completes, which executes the rest of `doService()`'s body, setting `_isLoading = false` and invoking `notfifyListeners()` again.
4. `sut.isLoading` at this point is `false`.

Comment: thank you for the detailed response and please pardon the typos in the original post (I fixed them if you want to fix your response). So what is preventing a “race condition” here (I realize there’s no parallel threading happening here) - I mean let’s say _service.runService is super short. Is the fact that the await inside sut.doService is registered before the await in the test?

Comment: @Mr.Oak There is no race condition.  There are two `Future`s: one returned by `sut.doService()` and one returned by `_service.runService()`.  The one returned by `sut.doService()` will not invoke completion callbacks until `doService()` has finished executing.  `doService()` will not finish executing until after the `Future` returned by `_service.runService()` completes and the rest of `doService`'s body executes.

Comment: Got you. Thanks for the clarification. You have been very helpful!